# Huawei Map always showed in top of stack widget in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, huawei-map-kit

When I use the Huawei map in my flutter app, I put it in the stack widget and put many floating buttons to access the map.

before the map is rendered the buttons show but after map rendering the buttons don't appear, but the buttons are still actionable.

this is the expected screen:

[image]

But the result of the code:

[image]

The code of this screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:huawei_map/map.dart';

class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapPageState createState() => _MapPageState();
}

class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {
  HuaweiMapController? _huaweiMapController;

  static const LatLng _centerPoint = const LatLng(41.043982, 29.014333);
  static const double _zoom = 12;

  final Set<Marker> _markers = {};
  final Set<Polyline> _polylines = {};
  final Set<Polygon> _polygons = {};
  final Set<Circle> _circles = {};

  bool _cameraPosChanged = false;
  bool _trafficEnabled = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void onMapCreated(HuaweiMapController controller) {
    _huaweiMapController = controller;
  }

  void clearMap() {
    setState(() {
      _markers.clear();
      _polylines.clear();
      _polygons.clear();
      _circles.clear();
    });
  }

  void log(msg) {
    print(msg);
  }

  void markersButtonOnClick() {
    if (_markers.length > 0) {
      setState(() {
        _markers.clear();
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _markers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('normal_marker'),
          position: LatLng(40.997802, 28.994978),
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
              title: 'Normal Marker Title',
              snippet: 'Description Here!',
              onClick: () {
                log("Normal Marker InfoWindow Clicked");
              }),
          onClick: () {
            log('Normal Marker Clicked!');
          },
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
        ));
        _markers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('draggable_marker'),
          position: LatLng(41.027335, 29.002359),
          draggable: true,
          flat: true,
          rotation: 0.0,
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: 'Draggable Marker Title',
            snippet: 'Hi! Description Here!',
          ),
          clickable: true,
          onClick: () {
            log('Draggable Marker Clicked!');
          },
          onDragEnd: (pos) {
            log("Draggable onDragEnd position : ${pos.lat}:${pos.lng}");
          },
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
        ));
        _markers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('angular_marker'),
          rotation: 45,
          position: LatLng(41.043974, 29.028881),
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
              title: 'Angular Marker Title',
              snippet: 'Hey! Why can not I stand up straight?',
              onClick: () {
                log("Angular marker infoWindow clicked");
              }),
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
        ));
      });
      _markers.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('colorful_marker'),
        position: LatLng(41.076009, 29.054630),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: 'Colorful Marker Title',
            snippet: 'Yeap, as you know, description here!',
            onClick: () {
              log("Colorful marker infoWindow clicked");
            }),
        onClick: () {
          log('Colorful Marker Clicked');
        },
        icon:
            BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueMagenta),
      ));
    }
  }

  void polygonsButtonOnClick() {
    if (_polygons.length > 0) {
      setState(() {
        _polygons.clear();
      });
    } else {
      List<LatLng> points1 = [
        LatLng(40.989306, 29.021242),
        LatLng(40.980753, 29.024590),
        LatLng(40.982632, 29.031885),
        LatLng(40.991273, 29.024676)
      ];
      List<LatLng> points2 = [
        LatLng(41.090321, 29.025598),
        LatLng(41.085146, 29.018045),
        LatLng(41.077124, 29.016844),
        LatLng(41.075441, 29.026285),
        LatLng(41.079582, 29.036928),
        LatLng(41.086828, 29.031435)
      ];

      setState(() {
        _polygons.add(Polygon(
            polygonId: PolygonId('polygon1'),
            points: points1,
            fillColor: Color.fromARGB(100, 129, 95, 53),
            strokeColor: Colors.brown,
            strokeWidth: 1,
            zIndex: 2,
            clickable: true,
            onClick: () {
              log("Polygon 1 Clicked");
            }));
        _polygons.add(Polygon(
            polygonId: PolygonId('polygon2'),
            points: points2,
            fillColor: Color.fromARGB(190, 242, 195, 99),
            strokeColor: Colors.yellow,
            strokeWidth: 1,
            zIndex: 1,
            clickable: true,
            onClick: () {
              log("Polygon 2 Clicked");
            }));
      });
    }
  }

  void polylinesButtonOnClick() {
    if (_polylines.length > 0) {
      setState(() {
        _polylines.clear();
      });
    } else {
      List<LatLng> line1 = [
        LatLng(41.068698, 29.030855),
        LatLng(41.045916, 29.059351),
      ];
      List<LatLng> line2 = [
        LatLng(40.999551, 29.062441),
        LatLng(41.025975, 29.069651),
      ];

      setState(() {
        _polylines.add(Polyline(
            polylineId: PolylineId('firstLine'),
            points: line1,
            color: Colors.pink,
            zIndex: 2,
            endCap: Cap.roundCap,
            startCap: Cap.squareCap,
            clickable: true,
            onClick: () {
              log("First Line Clicked");
            }));
        _polylines.add(Polyline(
            polylineId: PolylineId('secondLine'),
            points: line2,
            width: 2,
            patterns: [PatternItem.dash(20)],
            jointType: JointType.bevel,
            endCap: Cap.roundCap,
            startCap: Cap.roundCap,
            color: Color(0x900072FF),
            zIndex: 1,
            clickable: true,
            onClick: () {
              log("Second Line Clicked");
            }));
      });
    }
  }

  void circlesButtonOnClick() {
    if (_circles.length > 0) {
      setState(() {
        _circles.clear();
      });
    } else {
      LatLng point1 = LatLng(40.986595, 29.025362);
      LatLng point2 = LatLng(41.023644, 29.014032);

      setState(() {
        _circles.add(Circle(
            circleId: CircleId('firstCircle'),
            center: point1,
            radius: 1000,
            fillColor: Color.fromARGB(100, 249, 195, 53),
            strokeColor: Color(0xFFF9C335),
            strokeWidth: 3,
            zIndex: 2,
            clickable: true,
            onClick: () {
              log("First Circle clicked");
            }));
        _circles.add(Circle(
          circleId: CircleId('secondCircle'),
          center: point2,
          zIndex: 1,
          clickable: true,
          onClick: () {
            log("Second Circle Clicked");
          },
          radius: 2000,
          fillColor: Color.fromARGB(50, 230, 20, 50),
          strokeColor: Color.fromARGB(50, 230, 20, 50),
        ));
      });
    }
  }

  void moveCameraButtonOnClick() {
    if (!_cameraPosChanged) {
      _huaweiMapController!.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
          const CameraPosition(
            bearing: 270.0,
            target: LatLng(41.889228, 12.491780),
            tilt: 45.0,
            zoom: 17.0,
          ),
        ),
      );
      _cameraPosChanged = !_cameraPosChanged;
    } else {
      _huaweiMapController!.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
          const CameraPosition(
            bearing: 0.0,
            target: _centerPoint,
            tilt: 0.0,
            zoom: 12.0,
          ),
        ),
      );
      _cameraPosChanged = !_cameraPosChanged;
    }
  }

  void trafficButtonOnClick() {
    if (_trafficEnabled) {
      setState(() {
        _trafficEnabled = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _trafficEnabled = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final huaweiMap = HuaweiMap(
      onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
      buildingsEnabled: true,
      compassEnabled: true,
      zoomControlsEnabled: true,
      rotateGesturesEnabled: true,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      trafficEnabled: _trafficEnabled,
      markers: _markers,
      polylines: _polylines,
      polygons: _polygons,
      circles: _circles,
      onClick: (LatLng latLng) {
        log("Map Clicked at $latLng");
      },
      onLongPress: (LatLng latlng) {
        log("Map LongClicked at $latlng");
      },
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: _centerPoint,
        zoom: _zoom,
      ),
    );

    final markerButton = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: markersButtonOnClick,
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF9C335),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add_location, size: 36.0, color: Colors.black),
      ),
    );

    final circlesButton = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: circlesButtonOnClick,
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF9C335),
        child: const Icon(Icons.adjust, size: 36.0, color: Colors.black),
      ),
    );

    final polylinesButton = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: polylinesButtonOnClick,
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF9C335),
        child:
            const Icon(Icons.waterfall_chart, size: 36.0, color: Colors.black),
      ),
    );

    final polygonsButton = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: polygonsButtonOnClick,
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF9C335),
        tooltip: "Polygons",
        child: const Icon(Icons.crop_square, size: 36.0, color: Colors.black),
      ),
    );

    final clearButton = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => clearMap(),
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF9C335),
        tooltip: "Clear",
        child: const Icon(Icons.refresh, size: 36.0, color: Colors.black),
      ),
    );

    final moveCamreButton = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => moveCameraButtonOnClick(),
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF9C335),
        tooltip: "CameraMove",
        child: const Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active,
            size: 36.0, color: Colors.black),
      ),
    );

    final trafficButton = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => trafficButtonOnClick(),
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF9C335),
        tooltip: "Traffic",
        child: const Icon(Icons.traffic, size: 36.0, color: Colors.black),
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Map Kit', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF9C335),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            huaweiMap,
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    clearButton,
                    trafficButton,
                    moveCamreButton,
                    markerButton,
                    circlesButton,
                    polylinesButton,
                    polygonsButton
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you check with the Widget Inspector that the column of buttons is actually underneath the map? I'm wondering if it might be rendered outside of the screen instead

Comment: I am facing same problem right now, with the same code Google Maps were showing properly

Comment: https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-flutter-plugin/issues/191
So this is probably package issue, so we need to wait for package update I guess

Answer (score 0):

As per [flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html), the Opacity value `0` hides/does not render the widget. If you want to show the widget, use

`Opacity(opacity: 1.0,child: huaweiMap),`

Also, if you just want to change the visibility of the map dynamically, then consider using `Visibility` Widget as follows, As `Opacity` Widget is [**very performance expensive**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html).

```
bool visible = true; // You can change this normally using setState.
Visibility(visible: visible, child: huaweiMap),
```

If my answer solved your problem, please mark my answer as Correct. Thank you!

Comment: Tech Dev, I don't need to use Visibility or Opacity, it's just was to test.

Comment: Okay no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this issue, the problem is most probably caused by Flutter 3.x and it is resolved in the newest version of the map plugin, which is released on 06.30.2022.
Pls try to updated Huawei Map SDK version to **6.5.0.301** which may solve this issue.

[Version Change History](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050190751#section184112029133819).